# Setting Height of Pattern-Image for Canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I am drawing frames around some images.

This is my code for drawing the top frame:

```
this.frame.top.height = this.frame.top.height * this.resizeMultiplyer
const pattern = this.context.createPattern(this.frame.top, 'repeat');
console.log(this.frame.top.height);

console.log(this.frame.top.height);
this.context.fillStyle = pattern;
this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.frame.top.height);
```

My target is to resize the frame width with on different cases using a `resizeMultiplyer` that has value between 0 & 1.

Frame is getting drawn but and resize multiplier worked for frame drawing but frame image is not getting resized. So my image is basically cut off. I attaching my output that i am getting using the above code

**The output I'm getting:**

[Output I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhKHg.png)

**Expected output:**
[Output Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6MKO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making the pattern with the image, created another canvas with desired height & width and drew the image inside of it. Then created the pattern using that canvas.